# How can I tell if the DLC is active?

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I bought Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin for the PS3 recently. I received a physical copy of the Dark Souls 2 game (with the SotFS sleeve), and a code that would download all three pieces of DLC that are meant to come with the the Scholar version of the game. I activated the code on PSN (which downloaded 3 300kb files) and went about playing the game. All good as far as I could tell.

But, up until this moment, I've seen no sign that 'Scholar of the First Sin' is active on my game. I know the DLC areas have to be reached (at this point, I'm about twelve hours in, having just defeated the Lost Sinner) but I figured that the game should have mentioned it in some way at some point by now. I've seen no option to activate it beyond downloading the three pieces of DLC on PSN and the title screen shows the game as 'Dark Souls 2' with no subtitle of 'Scholar of the First Sin' (though I'm not sure if this would happen either way).

I've been avoiding guides for my first playthrough so I'm not sure when the Scholar himself should show up but should I be expecting any obvious signs at the start of the game that the DLC is active? Is this all a New Game plus thing, or should I just be waiting until much later in the game? I just don't want to have spent fifty hours playing the game only to find i missed one obscure option that invalidates everything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you bought wasn't Scholar of the First Sin, because the game should definitely have "Scholar of the First Sin" subtitles on it.

Video showing the start screen:

Video showing the PS3 disc:

The disc is shown at the [7:43 minute mark](https://youtu.be/tNFNGyeecc8?t=463).

I'd suggest going back to the store you bought it at and asking for an exchange, because it sounds like someone put the wrong disc in the SOTF case.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say you bought it from Gamestop or EB Games, since they are known for keeping discs out of their cases.

Comment: Son of a... Yes. I received the Dark Souls 2 original case (with the image of the Knight with his back to you) but with a SotFS cardboard sleeve (with the shadowy guy holding the crown). The original case was still in its plastic sleeve so it was new but i suppose that means they put the wrong version in. 

It did come with a leaflet containing the download codes and specifically mentioning SotFS which is how i figured it worked. I guess not.

To top it off, the store i bought it from was an indie store about a two hour drive away.

Ah well... i guess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: FWIW a year later (I guess this one's for posterity), that's pretty much the same thing on PS3, as the SotFS changes didn't get ported back to last-gen consoles. As long as you have the DLC installed, you're getting the correct DS2 last-gen experience.

(I could be wrong, but I believe the way to make sure you have the DLC on last-gen is to go to your key inventory and make sure you have a Dragon Talon, Frozen Flower, and one other thing I forget.)